# Sending notification from cloud server to devices on LAN

Tags: notifications, server

**I am trying to do the following:**

- I have my own server outside my LAN
- I have multiple clients on my LAN (behind my router)

I would like the server to notify a specific client about some event, after the client "registers" with the server. For example, the client may indicate which port is opened, and send the IP address.

All the questions I saw where related specifically to cloud services such as google cloud, but I am not interested in that.

**The problem I am facing is:**

- The server will see the router's IP instead of the device's IP. Say I open port 5555 on the clients, and the server sends a message to the router's IP at port 5555, will the router forward that to all the devices/ none of the devices/ or to only IP's with port forwarding?

**I am confused because:**
- In case it is not possible to send to a specific device, how can multiple devices browse the internet and use telnet/ ftp ...? Somehow the packets are finding their way to the correct device.

I know I am missing something, but I don't know what it is in order to ask the right technical question.

**The question is:**

Any ideas how to send specific message from a server to one of many clients on a LAN after the clients register with the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your LAN is connected to the external network and most likely doing NAT so that the internal IP addresses are different to the ones on the external network.

A widely used form of NAT not only translates IP addresses, but also Port numbers. This allows many internal LAN devices to share the same single IP on the external network. Home routers usually use this approach.

When an device on the internal network connects out. The router remembers which external port was used and directs any returning traffic to the correct internal device. This is how multiple devices running telnet / ftp etc can access the internet in answer to your first question.

However, a new connection coming into your LAN cannot be routed to a specific internal device without assistance. The router does not know where to send requests that it has not remembered previously.

However most routers have a feature called Port Forwarding where you can specify what to do with requests to specific ports from the external network. If you set up port forwarding and provide that information somehow to the server outside the LAN. It would be able to send requests to those ports and the router would pass it on to the matching internal IP and port number that you have pre-configured.

Please advise if you think you are not using NAT with Port translation (it has a number of different names). Somebody else will then be able to advise further

Comment: Say 2 devices access the internet at the same time.So the router does something like this? (source port: 10000, dest port: 80) for device1 and  (source port: 10001: dest port: 80) for device2, and server replies to port 10001 and port 10002? Source port is the router's port, dest port is the webpage port.

Comment: Yes, that's right. The router is expecting the response and sends it to the corresponding internal device. 
If the external server initiates the communication, then the router is not expecting the traffic and this is why you need to pre-configure port forwarding to help it out.